# Error: DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker

I got that error when I use a `BackgroundWorker`.  I use `ListView` control to show list and a `ItemsControl` to show some data of selected file.
When `SelectionChange` in `ListView` then `ItemsControl` should show data of selected item but it give that error:-

> error - Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject.

This is my code:

```
Variableholder vh=new Variableholder();
     public FileView(string path)
    {
    InitializeComponent();
    loadlist(path);
    listview.ItemsSource = vh.list();
    }

BackgroundWorker bworker = new BackgroundWorker();
public void loadlist(string path)
{
bworker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
bworker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
bworker.DoWork += bworker_Explorer;
bworker.ProgressChanged += bworker_AddItem;
bworker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
bworker.RunWorkerAsync(path);
}

public void bworker_Explorer(object sender,DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10;
Parallel.ForEach(e.Argument.ToString().Split(','),po, speratepath =>
{
......
}); }
public void bworker_AddItem(object sender,ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
if (e.UserState != null)
{
vh.list().Add(e.UserState as MusicTags);
}
}
void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
.......
}
private void listview_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
object o = listview.SelectedItem;
string filepath = (o as Tags).Filepath;
itemscontrol.ItemsSource = vh.list().Where(s => s.Filepath == filepath);
}
```

What i do?

Answer (score 0):

As this is an old post, I guess that you have already found solution, but for others stumbling over this:

You should create the `MusicTags` items on the main thread. It is not enough to add them to the `vh.list()` on the main thread